# Reading from a password file for tftpconnection

Tags: talend

I am trying to use tFTPConnection to download certain files from an FTP site.

It is a regular FTP connection, connecting on port 21.

I would like to be able to read the password from a file rather than hard coding the password to the job.

At the minute I'm simply making the connection and then printing success:

[image: Current job layout]

Any advice on how this could be approached or solved?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your job layout or better describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: Sure, i used 3 components (to test connection). tftpconnection, tfixedflowinput(where i just print success), tlogrow. tftpconnection is
joined to tfixedflowinput using oncomponentok and tfixedflowinput is joined to tlogrow using Main. If i type in the password and run 
the job it prints the following:
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3514
[statistics] connected
SUCCESS
[statistics] disconnected

I want to be able to pass in a  file instead of typing in the password. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talend supports the idea of context variables which allow you to define at run time the values used for them.

This is typically used so you can "contextualise" a connection and then deploy the job in multiple environments and have the connection be to the environment specific end point.

For instance, a job might need to connect to a database but that database is different for each of a development, a testing and a production environment.

Instead of hard coding the connection parameters to the job we instead create some context variables under a context group and refer to these context variables in the connection parameters:

[image: Contextualised tMySqlConnection]

Now, at run time we have the Talend job load these contexts from a file with the relevant connection parameters using an implicit context load:

[image: Example implicit context load settings]

In this case, the job will read the context variables at run time from a CSV called `test.csv` that looks like:

[image: Example contexts file]

Now, when this job is ran it will attempt to connect to localhost:3306/test with the root user and an empty password.

If we have another context file on another machine (but with the same file path) then this could refer to a database on some other server or simply using different credentials and the job would connect to this other database instead.

For your use case you can simply create a single context group with the FTP connection settings, including the password (or potentially just contextualise the password), and then refer to it in the same way:

[image: Contextualised password with a tFtpConnection component]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, much appreciated!!. I was going to try it out but am struggling with setting up my context. when i drag and drop a context load component, it already has two values which i am not able to delete since its disabled and it is not a globally shared context load.

Comment: The tContextLoad component requires you to pass some data to it in a key value pair. You could go down that route with a csv being read in from a tFileInputDelimited but you should use the implicit tContextLoad option as explained in my answer.

Comment: I created a file called partner_connection.csv with the following
password,abc123

Then in my job i read from this file with Implicit tContextLoad, and field separator set as ','. Then in my tftp connection for password
field i am using, 'context.password' but it gives me the following error message:

"password cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: **i renamed password to ftppassword since i wasn't sure if password is a key word.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3419
[statistics] connected
Implicit_Context_Context set key "ftppassword" with value "abc123"
Info: Parameter "ftppassword" is a new parameter of Implicit_Context_Context
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 ftppassword cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: You need to define the context variable before you can use it in your job. If you go to the Contexts tab you should be able to add a context and call it "password"